# Is there a way of learning intecting class type in ints ctor?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Suppose that we have an injectable class as follows. I want to know its generic T in its constructor.

```
@Injectable()
export class DInjectableClass<T extends IStore[]> {
         private strategy: IClientStore;
         constructor() {                
                 // ?? What is this type T , I wanna know and change behaviour
                 this.strategy = Fctry.getDefaultStore();                                
         }
}
```

So then, I'm dreaming to inject it as here below.

```
constructor(private _DinJect: DInjectableClass<[StoreA,StoreB]>) {

}
```

Somewhere else in the application it could be injected as following.

```
constructor(private _DinJect: DInjectableClass<[StoreC]>) {

}
```

What I'm looking for is knowing generic T beforehand in constructor of injectable class to align behavior accordingly.

- Is every @Injectable() is singleton and there isn't any way of different variation creations?
- Is this related to object creation order and there is no way to know T before its ctor ?

P.S. : Yes, after injection I can call a method of injected instance in the constructor and do whatever I want. But, if there is a way this would be better. 
This code builds and run but I still don't know what is T in ctor of injectable.

Comment: @estus you explain the problem but I believe the answer on the question I linked provides more detail as to how it can be achieved :-p anyway your answer was good so I +1ed it.

Comment: Thanks @estus. I understand from your answer that there is no reflection option on runtime as I wished.I voted to close my own question :)